# Querydsl with liquibase

Tags: java, maven, liquibase, querydsl

I would like to use Querydsl with code generation from SQL. The problem is that at development time I do not have a life database.

I hold the schema of my db in lqiuibase. So I would like to create the Querydsl code from the liquibase descriptions. Is this possible?

I guess I could create a H2 database in the target dir of my maven project using liquibase and then call the Querydsl code gen from there. Is this the way to go? Are there examples of this combination?

Comment: I don't know if question about example is actual, but here is working example of such combination
https://gist.github.com/c0ldd/2e1263598171d82b31040e752185f16d

Comment: Yes .. I am still interested in it .. thanks